# How to add a month by two

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select

First I am using this query to select the name of the month.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(DATENAME(month, (SELECT DATEPART(mm,lco_Date)+2
FROM aCT.dbo.iPLEX_BULK_PO_PARM WHERE Recid = '81a50399-e383-41a0-9196-2eaaa42b0ee8' AND season_id = '2015-SS')),1,3)
```

my lco_date month was 2 which is FEB. and then + 2 is 4 which is APR. Now when I run the whole code, it only display JAN and im confused.

I use this code to determine the month number and I succeed at the result of 4. It was the substring that i added but I am not getting the correct month name. Can anyone help?

```
(SELECT DATEPART(mm,lco_Date)+2
FROM aCT.dbo.iPLEX_BULK_PO_PARM WHERE Recid = '81a50399-e383-41a0-9196-2eaaa42b0ee8' AND season_id = '2015-SS')
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using DATEADD or any equivalent? DATEADD takes the datepart you want to add to(e.g: day, month, etc.), a number of interval you want to add, and your date as parameters. The number can either be positive, for dates in the future, or negative, for dates in the past.

```
SELECT DATEADD(month,2,lco_Date) AS OrderPayDate FROM aCT.dbo.iPLEX_BULK_PO_PARM WHERE Recid = '81a50399-e383-41a0-9196-2eaaa42b0ee8' AND season_id = '2015-SS')
```

for the full syntax, see here:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_dateadd.asp

Answer (score 0):

I assume because your sub-query returns the value 4 you are trying basically the following:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(DATENAME(month, 4),1,3)
```

But the 2nd argument must be a date, not just an integer. How about something like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(
DATENAME(month,
   CAST('2000-'
        + CAST((SELECT DATEPART(mm,lco_Date)+2 FROM aCT.dbo.iPLEX_BULK_PO_PARM WHERE Recid = '81a50399-e383-41a0-9196-2eaaa42b0ee8' AND season_id = '2015-SS') AS varchar)
        + '-01' AS DateTime)
   )
,1,3)
```